# What is the meaning of vertex tends to $ -\infty$ in the linked paper? How could be the probability equal to 0 in the given condition?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science

This is the link to the paper: https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1960-10.pdf

This is the snapshot of the equation:

[image: Textbook excerpt with equation]

Comment: Take the time to transcribe whatever your question is. Using pictures/papers in like you have will make the site unusable for future users and it hurts the site's ability to index and search.

Comment: what does mean the number of vertex in the graph tends to $-\infty$?

Comment: Where do they let the number of vertices tend to $-\infty$? I don't see it.

Comment: It's just not scanned very well. The things that look like $n\to-\infty$ actually say $n\to+\infty$ but the vertical part of the $+$ is very faint.

Comment: lets say if there are n labeled vertices $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$ and if $n\rightarrow -\infty$ than what will be the meaning of this?

Comment: @EspeciallyLime is right. $n$ is the number of vertices in this case, and it makes no sense at all for $n\to-\infty$

Comment: @That's what I am asking. Thank you all.